# focus Confirm not working in swal

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

i am creating sweet alert model then onclick event in open in model and by default auto focus in ok button how to do that? and my case cancel button auto focus it

```
 function saveCase() {
      if (recordedFullSymptoms.length != 0 && cust_preferenceFile.patient.patientId == 0) {
          swal({
              text: "You can save the case by selecting or creating new patient.",
              buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    text: "Ok",
                    value:1
                },
                Cancel: {
                    text:"Cancel",
                    value:2
                }
             },
             focusConfirm:true,
          }).then(value=> {
            if(value==1){
              getPartialView('PatientList', this);
            }  
          })
      }
      else
      {
          swal("Please select atleast one symptom to save case.");
      }
    }
```

Comment: cany ou try to explain it more precise? i don´t get your problem.

Comment: please check updated code

Comment: @DipGirase Are you having a similar issue like this: [Using SweetAlert2 for navigating inside the pages and not focusing on calling element](https://blog.praveen.science/using-sweetalert2-for-navigating-inside-the-pages-and-not-focusing-on-calling-element/)

Comment: no sir because i am trying to ok button on focus by default

Comment: @DipGirase check my eample if you are looking for something like this

Answer (score 4):

This below code works for me , I believe you are using sweetalert2 but with incorrect syntax for buttons. The correct syntax should be like below 
(used sweetalert 2 version 7.17.0)

```
function saveCase() {
      if (recordedFullSymptoms.length != 0 && cust_preferenceFile.patient.patientId == 0) {
          swal({
              text: "You can save the case by selecting or creating new patient.",
              showConfirmButton:true,
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
              cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
              focusConfirm:true
          }).then(result => {
            if (result.value){
              getPartialView('PatientList', this);
            }
            else if(result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel){
               swal('Cancelled');
            }
          });
      }
      else
      {
          swal("Please select atleast one symptom to save case.");
      }
    }
```

Here is a link to a working fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/p0rdmggu/16/

Comment: hi sir i have following the link but only show to ok button and not show to cancel button ....why?

Comment: and i am trying to  following code replace to my existing codeshowConfirmButton:true,
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
              cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',      then both button is show, but focus is cancel button

Comment: i am follow your example same

Comment: @DipGirase check the version of sweetalert2 in your end. And the order of css files in the jsfiddle. You have to follow the syntax I mentioned above to see both the buttons.

Comment: @DipGirase can you post a screenshot of how the focus is on cancel button? because I can see in the fiddle it's on ok button. of you use `focusConfirm:true`

Comment: hi sir i am not using sweetheart 2 , i am using boostrap sweetalert in version 2.1.0